How would I add netgear n-300/wna3100 usb adapter driver to ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
I recently made a Ubuntu server and don’t really have much ethernet right now and would like to use my usb adapter for now but I can’t seem to find support for this version of Ubuntu any help would be appreciated
